# How can I send multiple messages to a server, and have that server receive multiple messages instead of one big message [Python, Sockets]

Tags: python, sockets, events, tcp, selector

To clarify I have a script that:

1. sends some value to a server
2. receives a response from the server
3. sends a timestamp back to the server and close the connection

I would expect each message, bytes, would be send individually and have the server interpret that message individually. What is happening is the server is receiving the value along with the timestamp at the same time. I am using python, sockets, selectors. Below is how I send the data

```
# data.outb is empty
if not data.outb and gvl.global_Counter == 1:
    data.outb = bytes(gvl.global_Status, 'utf-8')
    sock.send(data.outb)

if data.outb and gvl.global_Counter == 1:
    # Truncate data.outb
      last_index = len(data.outb)
      data.outb = data.outb[last_index:]

    # Timestamp
      now = datetime.now()
      mytime_show = now.strftime('%Y-%M-%D %HH:%MM:%SS')

    # Encode the time into bits representation
      data.outb = bytes(mytime_show, 'utf-8')
      sent = sock.send(data.outb)
```

Essentially I first send `global_Status` and later I send the timestamp. On the server I look for a selector event read

```
# If NONE EMPTY PACKET
        if recv_data:
            readyData = recv_data.decode('utf-8')
```

And the readyData string is the two things I sent over, both in the same string.

Could anyone point me to the right direction in how I can go about making sure the server interprets the received data as distinct messages?

Answer (score 0):

That's the way TCP works.  It is not message-based.  Bytes are sent and received in the same order, but as many bytes as the network has transmitted are usually what is received.  You have to build a protocol on top of this behavior, buffer the data received and extract what you consider a complete message from the buffer.

You can use [`socket.makefile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) to wrap the socket in a file-like object that handles the buffering for you.  It can read lines (newline-terminated) via `.readline()` or set amounts of data with `.read(num_bytes)`.  It can also handle encoding/decoding of Unicode strings.

Example:

**server.py**

```py
import socket

with socket.socket() as server:
    server.bind(('', 5000))
    server.listen()

    while True:
        client, addr = server.accept()
        try:
            with client, client.makefile('r', encoding='utf8') as rfile:
                while True:
                    data = rfile.readline().rstrip('\n')
                    if not data: break
                    timestamp = rfile.readline().rstrip('\n')
                    print(f'[{timestamp}] {data}')
        except ConnectionResetError:
            print('Client aborted.')
```

**client.py**

```py
import socket
from datetime import datetime

with socket.socket() as client:
    client.connect(('localhost', 5000))

    with client.makefile('w', encoding='utf8') as wfile:
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        # Note that both lines are written all at once, but
        # the server will receive them a line at a time.
        wfile.write(f'some_data\n{timestamp}\n')
        # You can also write them one character at a time and it
        # will still work since makefile.readline() reads until a
        # newline is encountered.
        for c in 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog\n1999-12-31 23:59:59\n':
            wfile.write(c)
        # Note that if you don't close the socket, makefile buffers the writes and
        # may not send immediately.  Once you want the server to respond be sure to
        # flush the stream if not closing it right way.
        wfile.flush()
```

Output:

```
[2022-12-20 16:42:00] some_data
[1999-12-31 23:59:59] the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```